# Not all Divs are being returned by BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to figure out why the particular Div that am looking for is not found in the Soup Object.

So am looking for a Div with class name ***"row"***. Apparently there are 3 Divs with name ***"row"*** and the one I need is the 3rd one. And the soup object seems to contain only the first 2 instances.

```
<div class"row"> 
<div class="col-sm-12 bloc">
<div class="col-sm-12 bloc">
<div class="col-sm-12 bloc">
.
.
.
</div>
```

That is how the 3rd instance of the Div looks in the Web page's HTML. Following is the code am using :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("http://www.tomatonews.com/en/news-_2.html")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html5lib')

row = bsObj.find_all('div', class_='row')
```

Variable row returns first 2 instances of the Div and also returns length of 2. Even ***bsObj*** has only 2 Divs.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you need to wait a bit for the javascript to finish loading the 3rd div.row

Comment: Does it show if you put simply `soup.find_all('div')`?

Comment: @JustinEzequiel That was it! I was wondering how to actually 'wait' and thought let me just re-execute the  'BeautifulSoup()' statement separately after some time and I got that 3rd Div too. Haha Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a simple pause to execute JS:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("http://www.tomatonews.com/en/news-_2.html")

# pause to load page
time.sleep(10)

bsObj = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html5lib')

row = bsObj.find_all('div', class_='row')

print(len(row))
# 3
```

Comment: Yea that was the issue, I actually executed  `bsObj = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html5lib')` separately after sometime and it worked. The 'time.sleep' seems correct. Thanks.

Comment: @py92, Great, no problem!